# click button to open url but from ts function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Requirement:

We need to open a php page on a new window. We have achieved like this way as shown below

`.html code`

```
 <a target="_blank" href="{{pdf}}">Download Pdf</a>
```

`.ts code`

```
ngOnInit()
{
this.loggedinuser = localStorage.getItem("USERNAME");
console.log(this.loggedinuser);
this.pdf = 'http://219.90.67.154/report-service/quicktask/TCPDF/examples/test-tcpdf.php?loggedinuser='+this.loggedinuser;
}
```

But we want to achieve it differently. Need to click a button from html, which will call a function, from this function everything should happen.

`.html`

```
 <button ion-button  (click)="saveit">Save</button>
```

`.ts`

```
saveit(){
// the url,html tag should be called from here , how ?
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - Redirect to an external URL and open in a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775017/angular-2-redirect-to-an-external-url-and-open-in-a-new-tab)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45517884/drop-down-menu-option-selected-based-on-url-paramater/45517973

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `window.open` method of javascript to open URL on button click, like this -

```
 <button ion-button  (click)="saveit()">Save</button>
saveit(){
// the url,html tag should be called from here , how ?
window.open(URL);
}
```

Comment: Dont forget that it should be (click)="saveit()"

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<button ion-button (click)="saveit()">Save</button>
```

Component:

```
saveit() {
    let loggedinuser = localStorage.getItem("USERNAME");
    let url = 'http://219.90.67.154/report-service/quicktask/TCPDF/examples/test-tcpdf.php?loggedinuser=' + this.loggedinuser;   
    window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```